# Make use of tablet camera within website

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, canvas

I am trying to make a website for tablets.
In this application i would like to make use of the camera that is in the tablet.
After a few hours i finally got it to work. So now it is possible to hit the button and the camera will start. After that the image will be written to a html5 canvas.

The problem that i have been having now is that i would like to repeat this process 4 times. So there have to be 4 upload buttons and 4 canvas. Each upload should be made to its own canvas. and be saved in the local storage. I have been trying real hard and tried multiple things but i just can't figure it out.

The problem should be in these 2 functions

```
    function readURL(input) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('maincanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imageObj = new Image();

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                imageObj.src = e.target.result;



                var newWidth = imageObj.width * 0.5;
                var newHeight = imageObj.height * 0.5;

                canvas.width = newWidth;
                canvas.height = newHeight;

                context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

                var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);

                localStorage.setItem("image", data);

                document.getElementById('preview').src = data;

            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }

    }

    $("#uploader").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bagmaendene/8Locnjp2/

Would be really great if soembody could help me do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can't repeat ID's in a page and you would need to set different storage keys also. Otherwise not really clear what problems you are having specifically

Comment: The main problem that i was having was, was that when i made another upload button i couldent get it to save on a new canvas. It would always be overwriting the old one.

Comment: right, so you would need perhaps array of canvas or look within a parent div wrapper for instances

Comment: Do you maybe have a example? I tried multiple different things but i can't get it to work...